# struct array initialize with a variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, struct

I am trying to create an array with a known size.

```
struct  AudioStreamPacketDescription
{
    SInt64  mStartOffset;
    UInt32  mVariableFramesInPacket;
    UInt32  mDataByteSize;
};
typedef struct AudioStreamPacketDescription AudioStreamPacketDescription;
```

here this gives me null result for the struct array;
`AudioStreamPacketDescription tempDesc[packetsFilledDesc];`

[image]

if I do 
`AudioStreamPacketDescription tempDesc[24];`

it gives me correct value;

[image]

how can I initialize array size with a variable?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a C code, I would dynamically allocate the array:

```
AudioStreamPacketDescription *tempDesc = malloc (packetsFilledDesc * sizeof(struct AudioStreamPacketDescription));
...
free(tempDesc);
```

Comment: this is just one object though I need to pass an array[] to another function.